# Precedence of custom operators in F#

Tags: f#, operators

I'm trying to create operators similar to (&&) and (||), and with the same precedence.

My code is:

```
let (&&.) = (&&)
let (||.) = (||)
printf $"{true ||. true &&. false} = {true || true && false}"
```

This prints "False = True".

As I understand it, in F# the precedence of custom operators is defined by their first characters.
Why do I get this output, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is working as intended. According to [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#operator-precedence) `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, but `&&.` and `||.` have the same precedence (as instances of `&op` and `|op`).

To fix it, you could choose an operator with higher precedence for your custom "and" function, like this:

```ml
let (^^.) = (&&)
let (||.) = (||)
printf $"{true ||. true ^^. false} = {true || true && false}"   // "true = true"
```

[image]